# model タグを一括で消したい

Tags: 討議, 完了, タグ

[model](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/model) というタグがあり、現在 9 つの質問にこのタグが付いています。

なのですが、現在このタグのタグ wiki は無く、結果として機械学習で使われる数理モデルの意味での「model」と Model View Controller の意味での「model」とで混同が起こっています。

英語版にも [model] タグは存在し、こちらは Model View Controller の意味での「model」であるとタグ wiki が書かれています: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/model

ただ、この [model](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/model) というタグが質問を探すときの助けになるように思えません。単に削除するので良い気がしているのですが、如何でしょうか。

質問によっては Model View Controller のためのタグである [mvc](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mvc) に付け替えるのもアリかなと考えています。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

+5 投票も集まっていたので、自分で一括削除を行いました。待っていればタグ自体が消えるはず……です（多分）。